# Extract values within single curly braces

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get a collection **{value}** of a string using ***Regular Expression***.

For example:

> lorem ipsum {field1} lorem ipsum {field2} lorem ipsum field1 lorem ipsum field2 {{field3}}

I would get: `{field1} and {field2}`

I try this:

```
string pattern =@"\[(?>[^\{\}]+)*\]";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < matches.Count; ctr++)
{
    string field = matches[ctr].Value;
    // ... ommitted...
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negative lookarounds to only get the `{...}` substrings not having `{` in front or `}` right after them:

```
(?<!{){[^{}]+}(?!})
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%7B)%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%7D(%3F!%7D)&i=lorem%20ipsum%20%7Bfield1%7D%20lorem%20ipsum%20%7Bfield2%7D%20lorem%20ipsum%20field1%20lorem%20ipsum%20field2%20%7B%7Bfield3%7D%7D)

[image]

- `(?<!{)` -  a negative lookbehind failing the match if there is a `{` before the current position
- `{` - a literal `{`
- `[^{}]+`  - 1 or more symbols other than `{` and `}`
- `}` -  a literal `}`
- `(?!})` - a negative lookahead failing the match if there is `}` right after the previous `}`.

Comment: Note that in case you also want to match values like `{val1}}` and `{{val2}` you will need to use alternation: `(?<!{){[^{}]+}|{[^{}]+}(?!})`.