# Regex to match string between curly braces (that allows to escape them via 'doubling')

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I was using the regex from [Extract values within single curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738558/extract-values-within-single-curly-braces):

```cs
(?<!{){[^{}]+}(?!})
```

However, it does not cover the user case #3 (see below).

I would like to know if it's possible to define a regular expression that satisfied the use cases below

#### Use case 1

Given:

```
Hola {name}
```

It should match **{name}** and capture **name**

But I would like to be able to escape curly braces when needed by doubling them, like C# does for interpolated strings. So, in a string like

#### Use case 2

```
Hola {name}, this will be {{unmatched}}
```

The **{{unmatched}}** part should be ignored because it uses them *doubled*. Notice the `{{` and `}}`.

#### Use case 3

In the last, most complex case, a text like this:

```
Buenos {{{dias}}}
```

The text **{dias}** should be a match (and capture **dias**) because the first outer-most doubled curly braces should be interpreted just like another character (they are escaped) so it should match: `{{`**{dias}**`}}`

My ultimate goal is to replace the matches later with another string, like a variable.

## EDIT

This **4th use case** pretty much summarized the whole requirements:

Given:
`Hola {name}, buenos {{{dias}}}`

Results in:

- Match 1:

  - Matched text: `{name}`
  - Captured text: `name`
- Match 2:

  - Matched text: `{dias}`
  - Captured text: `dias`

Comment: Do you mean you want to match `{dias}` in `{{{dias}}}`, not `{{dias}}`? The `}}` and `{{` are escaped braces *outside* of matches?

Comment: Try `Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!{)(?:{{)*({[^{}]*})(?:}})*(?!})").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)`

Comment: To optionally match doubles curlys `(?<!{)({{)?{[^{}]+(?(1)}})}(?!})`https://regex101.com/r/d3pcbw/1

Comment: You may use `(?:{{|}})+|({[^}]+})` and work with captured group #1. [See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eazzHB/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I mean that in **{{{dias}}}**, it should match **{dias}**, but only capture **dias**. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, moved `{` and `}` outside of the capturing group in Solution 1 and into the lookarounds in Solution 2. You can safely use either of my solutions that support any amount of escaped braces on each end.

Comment: Now, the only question is, should the `{` count before the match be equal to the `}` count after? The other answer assumes the counts should be identical (though, there is only one escaped brace support).

Comment: How about e.g. [`(?<![^{]{){[^}{]+}`](https://regex101.com/r/GIuSMS/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I guess that uneven-and-unescaped braces (braces without a pair) shouldn't be allowed. However, escaped braces are OK in any case. Examples: **This string is {{{not valid}}** or **This is is also invalid}**, **This is }} valid**. The rule to follow is exactly the same as the C# interpolated strings.

Comment: Ok, so if you need to get `not valid` from `This string is {{{not valid}}` string, use my solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?<!{)(?:{{)*{([^{}]*)}(?:}})*(?!})
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%7b%29%28%3f%3a%7b%7b%29*%7b%28%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%29%7d%28%3f%3a%7d%7d%29*%28%3f!%7d%29&i=Hola+%7bname%7d%2c+this+will+be+%7b%7bunmatched%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7bdias%7d%7d%7d).

In C#, you can use

```cs
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!{)(?:{{)*{([^{}]*)}(?:}})*(?!})").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```

Alternatively, to get full matches, wrap the left- and right-hand contexts in lookarounds:

```cs
(?<=(?<!{)(?:{{)*{)[^{}]*(?=}(?:}})*(?!}))
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3c!%7b%29%28%3f%3a%7b%7b%29*%7b%29%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%28%3f%3d%7d%28%3f%3a%7d%7d%29*%28%3f!%7d%29%29&i=Hola+%7bname%7d%2c+this+will+be+%7b%7bunmatched%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7bdias%7d%7d%7d).
In C#:

```cs
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=(?<!{)(?:{{)*{)[^{}]*(?=}(?:}})*(?!}))")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

**Regex details**

- `(?<=(?<!{)(?:{{)*{)` - immediately to the left, there must be zero or more `{{` substrings not immediately preceded with a `{` char and then `{`
- `[^{}]*` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `(?=}(?:}})*(?!}))` - immediately to the right, there must be `}`, zero or more `}}` substrings not immediately followed with a `}` char.

Comment: I've tried the [linked regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3c!%7b%29%28%3f%3a%7b%7b%29*%7b%29%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%28%3f%3d%7d%28%3f%3a%7d%7d%29*%28%3f!%7d%29%29&i=Hola+%7bname%7d%2c+this+will+be+%7b%7bunmatched%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7bdias%7d%7d%7d) and in "Buenos {{{dias}}}" the matched string is **dias**,but it should match **{dias}**, and capture **dias**.

Comment: @SuperJMN Use `(?<=(?<!{)(?:{{)*){([^{}]*)}(?=(?:}})*(?!}))`.

Answer (score 5):

To optionally match double curly's, you could use an if clause and take the value from capture group 2.

```
(?<!{)({{)?{([^{}]+)}(?(1)}})(?!})
```

*Explanation*

- `(?<!{)` Assert not `{` directly to the left
- `({{)?` Optionally capture `{{` in **group 1**
- `{([^{}]+)}` Match from `{` till `}` without matching `{` and `}` in between
- `(?(1)}})` If clause, if group 1 exists, match `}}`
- `(?!})` Assert not `}` directly to the right

[.Net regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%7b%29%28%7b%7b%29%3f%7b%28%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%29%7d%28%3f%281%29%7d%7d%29%28%3f!%7d%29&i=Hola+%7bname%7d%0d%0aHola+%7bname%7d%2c+this+will+be+%7b%7bunmatched%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7bdias%7d%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7bdias%7d%7d%7d%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7bdias%7d) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/bUArlM)

[image]

```
string pattern = @"(?<!{)({{)?{([^{}]+)}(?(1)}})(?!})";
string input = @"Hola {name}
    Hola {name}, this will be {{unmatched}}
    Buenos {{{dias}}}";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Output

```
name
name
dias
```

---

If the double curly's should be balanced, you might use this approach:

```
(?<!{){(?>(?<={){{(?<c>)|([^{}]+)|}}(?=})(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))}(?!})
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%7b%29%7b%28%3f%3e%28%3f%3c%3d%7b%29%7b%7b%28%3f%3cc%3e%29%7c%28%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%29%7c%7d%7d%28%3f%3d%7d%29%28%3f%3c-c%3e%29%29*%28%3f%28c%29%28%3f!%29%29%7d%28%3f!%7d%29&i=Hola+%7bname%7d%0d%0aHola+%7bname%7d%2c+this+will+be+%7b%7bunmatched%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7bdias%7d%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7b%7b%7bdias%7d%7d%7d%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7b%7btest%7dhello%7d%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7b%7b%7ba%7d%7ddias%7b%7ba%7d%7d%7d%7d%7d%0d%0a%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7b%7b%7ba%7b%7bi%7d%7dab%7d%7d%7d%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7bdias%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7b%7b%7bdias%7d%7d%7d%7d%7d%0d%0aBuenos+%7bdias%7d%7d%7d%0d%0a)